# How the snake laid down in the ground

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

This my puzzle is inspired by [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52259/36-length-snake-in-a-6x6-grid).

A sleeping snake has 36 consecutively numbered segments. 
It is hidden in a 6x6 gridded square ground.
Each snake's segment fits exactly in 1 grid square.
The first segment is the snake's head.
Every two consecutive segment lie in grid that share an edge.
Each row has only 1 special segment.
(A special segment is an $n$th segment where $n$ is a multiple of 6.)
Each column also has only 1 special segment.
(Note : It is like placing 6 rooks in the chessboard, where the rooks do not attack each other.)

A snake charmer knows the position of its head and its tail.

This picture shows the snake's head and tail.
[image]

> Note :  The Head and Tail in the picture just show where the head and
>   tail are, and are not placed facing any particular direction.

**How was the snake lying down (asleep) on the ground?.**

Comment: Impossible, because the bottom-right corner is inaccesible

Comment: @boboquack think again. It is accessible .

Comment: Are diagonal segments possible?

Comment: @Nautilus no diagonals. I will edit the question.

Comment: @boboquack Why not? It's perfectly possible if e1 is the first segment.

Comment: Is the first segment the head? i.e the piece of the snake five pieces from the head is accessible

Comment: @Wen1now : Yes, the first segment is the head.

Comment: @Nautilus how? You can't go into the corner and back out of it, because the tail piece is facing the wrong way.

Comment: @boboquack the picture just show where the tail is, not the orientation.

Comment: If the picture is not meant to indicate the orientation of the tail, I suggest you draw it so it doesn't point to an orientation, like it's drawn here...

Comment: @ffao : Thank you, I think the last edit have made the puzzle clear (Without change the picture). It takes times to edit the picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the snake sleeps like (picture could have been better):

> [image]
>
>  You only know the endpoint, but not the manner it is turned. So the bottom-right corner can still be reached. The yellow numbers are the multiples of 6 of which only one had to be in a row and column.

Explanation:

> because of the location of the tail the botom right corner must be '35' with '34' above. For the first 6 numbers it had to be a 'U' shape as else there was not enough room for all 6-multiples to fit in separate rows and columns. So, I first tried the number '6' on the current position of the '2', but then I couldn't get the whole snake in. After I had the '6' the possible locations of the 6-multiples was a good help to fit the rest of the snake.

Comment: Correct! Could you explain how do you solve this puzzle?

Comment: +1 for correct answer. Still waiting for your logic explanation.

Comment: @JamalSenjaya: I've added an explanation of how I found the answer.